# VisibilityAwareImageButton Usage

Tags: android, android-layout, android-design-library

I was recently working with ImageButtons and I came across this new type of ImageButton 'VisibilityAwareImageButton'. It would be really helpful if someone could tell me the usage of this ImageButton and how is it different from the regular ImageButton? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the full source for `VisibilityAwareImageButton`.

```
class VisibilityAwareImageButton extends ImageButton {

    private int mUserSetVisibility;

    public VisibilityAwareImageButton(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public VisibilityAwareImageButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public VisibilityAwareImageButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        mUserSetVisibility = getVisibility();
    }

    @Override
    public void setVisibility(int visibility) {
        internalSetVisibility(visibility, true);
    }

    final void internalSetVisibility(int visibility, boolean fromUser) {
        super.setVisibility(visibility);
        if (fromUser) {
            mUserSetVisibility = visibility;
        }
    }

    final int getUserSetVisibility() {
        return mUserSetVisibility;
    }
}
```

It appears to be almost exactly the same as a regular `ImageButton`, only it keeps track of the last visibility actually set by the user.  The only usage I can find is in the [`FloatingActionButton`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.java) source.  It is used to keep track of what the user wants the visibility of the view to be while it does it's own internal changes and animations. i.e.

```
if (child.getUserSetVisibility() != VISIBLE) {
    // The view isn't set to be visible so skip changing it's visibility
    return false;
}
```

It's in the design support library and has package visibility, so it seems like Google intends on using it internally (and seemingly only for the FAB implementation at this time).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - Is there any recommended strategy to set the visibility from outside for FABs?